# IntelliSense working only in some Jupyter Notebooks but not all of them - VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, intellisense, docstring

After spending several hours reading similar questions and trying several things, I decided of posting the question myself.

As the title suggests, IntelliSense is working well when I work with some other languages (like C or C++) and also working perfectly well with Python. But the problem is that is doesn't work with every Jupyter notebook, but it is working in some projects..

- [Project where creating a new Jupyter notebook, works with
  IntelliSense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFtXu.jpg)
- [Project where creating a new Jupyter notebook, doesn't works with
  IntelliSense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBbB0.jpg)

Can anyone spot the reason for this??

To add further information:

1. I edited the setting.json file to enable IntelliSense

   ```
   // Controls if quick suggestions should show up while typing
   "editor.quickSuggestions": {
       "other": true,
       "comments": false,
       "strings": false
   },
   ```

   [Settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzeM5.jpg)
2. and I have also  Pylance activated as well in settings.json:

   ```
   "python.languageServer": "Pylance"
   ```

   According to this comment :
   https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1375#issuecomment-731171300

   in this issue :
   https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1375#

What I have noticed is that sometimes the method np.arrange() gets recognized as a Method (According to the "Cube" icon in the first picture) and in this case everything works fine, but in another projects, the method np.arrange() gets recognized only as a property( according to the "Wrench" icon in the second picture)

- This explanation of the icons in VSCode: [IntelliSense's Types of
  completition, (Method and Property icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svZYm.png)

So my guess is that some module or something might not be loading properly in to the project.

Many thanks for your help in advance!!!

Comment: Do you reload VS Code after using the language service provided by "Pylance"? I tested Jupyter in VS Code, and its auto-completion and docsing are displayed. It is recommended that you reinstall the python extension, Jupyter extension, then reload VS Code and wait for the language service to load.

Comment: Hi @Jill, first of all, many thanks for taking the time to review my issue! I've done everything you said, and I got to the point where I can see the autocompletion, but not the docstring, which actually the most important part for me.<br/> Any further suggestions?

Comment: -What extensions did you use in VS Code? It is recommended that you "diasble" other unused VS Code extensions to avoid the impact of incompatibility between them. In addition, please use the latest version of the Python extension and the Pylance extension.